# Как создать наклонённую кнопку c++ winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi

Как я могу создать кнопку под наклоном на чистом c++ и winApi?
Кнопка должна реагировать точно по своей форме, вид и реакция кнопки (вкл, серое, фокус и т.д.) не важны.

Например: в браузере с помощью css можно наклонить кнопку

```
button{
      transform: rotateX(45);
}
```

Comment: Не нашел ваш прошлый вопрос, поэтому ловите +1 еще раз. Уточнения: Вопрос о стандартной кнопке Windows (которая в каждой версии ОС выглядит как родная)? Сама кнопка должна реагировать на курсор точно по своей форме, или прямоугольной области будет достаточно? Кнопка должна поддерживать все стандартные состояния (вкл, серое, фокус, итп)?

Comment: здравствуйте! я удалил прошлый вопрос во избежании дубликатов. Да, кнопка должна реагировать точно по своей форме, вид и реакция кнопки (вкл, серое, фокус и т.д.) не важны

Comment: Во избежание дубликатов следовало отредактировать старый вопрос, а не создавать новый, который наверняка будет закрыт по той же причине.

Comment: @user7860670 прошу вас писать только по делу, ведь прошлое не исправишь!

Comment: Нет, под вопросом как раз есть кнопка Править, которой и надо было воспользоваться для редактирования предыдущего закрытого вопроса.